# Estimating the Hurst parameter in Python

Tags: python, openflow, pox

I'm working on a POX controller. Part of it's functionality relies on checking the value of H (Hurst exponent), once every *X amount of seconds* (for arguments sake lets say 10). I've found the PyEEG module, which I'll be using for its 'hurst' function. The function takes a time series as a parameter and returns the value of H (which should be in between 0 and 1) for the provided time series.

Given that I need to check the current level of *H* every *X* seconds, I presume I'll need to dump the raw data into a time series and pass this to the function. I'll collect this from every packet that is checked during a predefined period of time (lets say 5 seconds).

My question is this - Which specific piece of data is it that I will need to extract from each packet passed to my controller during this length of time, and pass as an argument to the 'hurst' function? Am sure this sounds incredibly stupid, however I've read numerous academic papers looking for guidance, which all provide examples that aren't related to the data I'm using... They either use PRNGs to generate a set of number sequences and create a time series or are completely unrelated to network-traffic (i.e. finance etc...). I understand there are probably people that will read this and think it's a stupid way of doing what I want to do, however, this is a small but integral function of the code for the POX controller I'm attempting to write.